# Can i get the rows that isn't repeated inverted in my table?

Tags: sql

I have a table:
1|5
2|4
3|3
4|2
5|1
(the actual table is a lot of names and what I want is to just get one set of each combination)
is there a way to get just the rows that are not repeated inverted at the end?
I just want the:
1|5
2|4
3|3
rows.. can i do this in sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this solve your problem:

```
select *
from MyTable
where ColA <= ColB
```

**Edit:** Ok, if you have cases like 20, 5 then you could use this:

```
with allpairs as (
    select ColA, ColB
    from MyTable
    where ColA <= ColB

    union all

    select ColB, ColA
    from MyTable
    where ColB < ColA
)
select distinct *
from allpairs
```

Comment: It may, however, what if the values in the table were 20 and 5 where there was no corresponding 5 and 20.

Answer (score 3):

Something like:

```
select distinct(case when x<y then x||'|'||y else y||'|'||x end) from table;
```

Should work on Oracle, in different db use equivalent of case.

Test:

```
select distinct(case when x<y then x||'|'||y else y||'|'||x end) from 
(select 1 x,2 y from dual
union
select 1 x,2 y from dual
union
select 1 x,3 y from dual
union
select 3 x,2 y from dual
union
select 2 x,1 y from dual
);
```

Returns:
1|2
1|3
2|3

Comment: Just about where I was going... My only concern to the person posting was if he/she wanted to retain the original columns as columns and not piped together.